# Filter RxJava/ReactiveX Observable based on Observable condition

Tags: rx-java2

I need to filter a Stream of observable Values based on some condition which is modeled as Observable inside my Value.

```
class ValueObject {

    BehaviorSubject<Boolean> condition = ...;

}
```

...

```
valueObjects.filter(valueObject -> condition).subscribe(valueObject -> ...);
```

My goal is to have the stream firing if a) a new Value was pushed or b) the condition for the filter changed.

(Bonus: do that same thing with lists of ValueObjects (`Observable<List<ValueObject>>`) and that ugly `Object[]`-`combineLatest`...)

Is there some kind of best practice for that problem? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want here. When a `valueObject` arrives, you want to let it pass if the `condition` `BehaviorSubject` is currently `true`? If the `condition` turns `true` what `valueObject` would be sent forward if there isn't any currently from `valueObjects`?

Comment: yep - and if the condition turns false, it should signal, too. (eg. Optional.empty or an empty collection for lists of value-objects)

Comment: "condition turns false, it should signal, too" How? And how frequently? What is your original task you try to solve?